# Change MAPI profile exchange service OST file with profman/redemption

Tags: mapi, outlook-redemption

I need to do the steps 9-12 that are exlained in this KB programatically with profman/redemption on an existing exchange MAPI profile (not while it's being created).

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2752583/en-us

Is it possible, how?

PS: I need to change the OST file to another existing OST

As always,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to change the `PR_PROFILE_OFFLINE_STORE_PATH_W` property - loop through all `MSEMS` services in the profile, for all providers in those services, open their profile sections and if `PR_PROFILE_OFFLINE_STORE_PATH` property is set, replace its value.

You can see the profile data in OutlookSpy (I am its author - click IProfAdmin or IMAPISession | AdminServices.

Comment: PATH_W, PATH or PATH_A do I need to check/set ?

Comment: The latest versions of Outlook use _W, but it might be a good idea to check both.

Comment: I can sucessfully change the OST file to another one, however I'm getting the error message that the ost file has been configured to be used with another exchange account. To your knowlegde, is it possible to reuse an ost file from another account? We're looking for a way to reduce bandwith while the ost file will be resync when users will change from one account to another.

Comment: No, an OST file can only be used in the profile used to create it